# Quiet mode for pdfLaTeX in emacs

Tags: emacs, customization, pdflatex, verbose

I've begun to use emacs as a pdfLaTeX writer/compiler, which is just brilliant.

However, whenever I execute TeX file (`C-c C-f`), which currently executes the following:

```
(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")
```

I get an *awful* lot of verbose output from pdfLaTeX.

Is there a way to change this behaviour? I thought of `(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex -interaction=batchmode")` but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing LaTex in emacs you should use the package named AUCTeX. This fixes your problem and has a lot of extra functionality.

Comment: I'd like to install AUCTeX in my Emacs distribution. Is it available in the Emacs package manager, and if so, under which category?

Comment: Thank you - your solution worked really well. Note that the [AUCTeX website](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) states that at least Emacs 24 is required.

Comment: There are also older versions of AUCTeX that do not require emacs 24.